# Is it possible to modify the Lua script to require?

Tags: c++, lua, require

When I call `require 'name'` in Lua, the name can be either a preloaded module name or a file that exists in a current working directory.

I have the following two questions:

A. I would like to know if it's possible to find out whether a preloaded module or a file will be required right before it will be required.

B. And if it's a file, I want to modify the script which will be required (by prepending/appending some code on top of existing one) and then require the modified script finally.

Are `A` and `B` both possible?

P.S.: I'm using Lua with C++.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry I edited that part.

Comment: Now I get it, good edit. I can however not answer, sorry.

Comment: In case you didn't know, `require 'name'` is the same as `require('name')`. In other words, it just calls whatever function value that the require variable refers to at the time the statement is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are A and B both possible?

Yes, as you can write your own "require" function that does what you need (including everything you describe). You can also look at [package.searchers](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers), as registering your function as one of the searchers may be enough to implement what you want.

Comment: I would appreciate if you take a look at my edited question.

Comment: I don't see a problem with what you are doing, so if it works for you, then by all means use it.