# How to check if preloaded module exists in Lua using C++

Tags: c++, lua

I would like to know how to check if a preloaded module exists or not in Lua using C++.

**My Code :**

```
#include "lua.hpp"

bool isModuleAvailable(lua_State *L, std::string name)
{
    //what should be here?
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function()\n"
                         "local a = {}\n"
                         "return a\n"
                     "end\n");
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['B'] = function()\n"
                         "local b = {}\n"
                         "return b\n"
                     "end\n");

    if (isModuleAvailable(L, "A"))
        std::cout << "Module Available" << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Module Not Available" << '\n';

    if (isModuleAvailable(L, "B"))
        std::cout << "Module Available" << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Module Not Available" << '\n';

    if (isModuleAvailable(L, "C"))
        std::cout << "Module Available" << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Module Not Available" << '\n';
    lua_close(L);
}
```

**The Result I get :**

```
Module Not Available
Module Not Available
Module Not Available
```

**The Result I want :**

```
Module Available
Module Available
Module Not Available
```

How can I create `isModuleAvailable()` function so my code can work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check whether the field `package.preload[name]` is `nil`.  I also renamed the function to `isModulePreloaded` because that's what is checks.

```
bool isModulePreloaded(lua_State *L, std::string const &name) {
    lua_getglobal(L, "package");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, name.c_str());
    bool is_preloaded = !lua_isnil(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 3);
    return is_preloaded;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I would appreciate if you could please take a look at my question which I just edited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701228/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-lua-script-to-require

Comment: @ZackLee Don't edit your question when it already has received answers.  You are just making the answers invalid which won't help anyone coming across this thread.  Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Sorry I will ask a new question then.

Comment: @ZackLee Also, loading modules and putting them into `package.preload` is completely nonsensical because they are already cached automatically in `package.loaded`.

Comment: @ZackLee Looking back I probably should never have posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925130) using `package.preload` because now that you have this [hammer, everything looks like a nail](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail).

Comment: Sorry I will re-think about my design.

Comment: @ZackLee Downvote is not mine.  If you want we can discuss this in chat.